# Download update and install APK hosted in private webserver

Tags: android

Actually I am developing an private android application for my firm, and its intended for our employees only.
I am currently struggling with download and update activity.
Please post some example or share link from where I can get reference.

Comment: I think you have to specifie the question. Do you looking for a continuous  integration and / or continius deployment  solution? Maybe this artical can be helpful for you 

https://medium.com/the-telegraph-engineering/android-continuous-delivery-fb41da63176

Answer (score 0):

I've done this like one week ago, here you have an example of an activity that show's a background image while it check's for updates.
[Activity](https://codeshare.io/aJyR6n)

[FileProvider.Java](https://codeshare.io/5Q7RQJ)

[You need to put this in your manifest inside application tag](https://codeshare.io/G6lEdQ)

Comment: Dear sir I have tried with similar code , but I was getting error in write storage.
Although I have added required permissions in project gradle

Comment: Dear sir
Now m able to download the APK but it's not installing it

Answer (score 0):

The onpostexecute

@Override

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        bar.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Done",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(testactivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("DO you want to Install Updates?")
                    .setCancelable(false).setTitle("Install Update").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_logoutred)
                    .setPositiveButton("Install", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            OpenNewVersion();

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();



        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And openNewVersion

```
MANSOOR RAZA:
```

void OpenNewVersion() {

```
    Intent downloadIntent;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/";

        File fileLocation = new File(PATH, "app-release.apk");
        Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,  SHARED_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, fileLocation);
        downloadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        downloadIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        downloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        downloadIntent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(downloadIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            this.grantUriPermission(packageName, apkUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
    }else {
        File fileLocation = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "app-release.apk");
        downloadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        downloadIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        downloadIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileLocation), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    }
    this.startActivity(downloadIntent);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "update Done",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

}

Answer (score 0):

@Override

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        bar.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Done",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(testactivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("DO you want to Install Updates?")
                    .setCancelable(false).setTitle("Install Update").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_logoutred)
                    .setPositiveButton("Install", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            OpenNewVersion();

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();



        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And my openNewVersion

```
MANSOOR RAZA:
```

void OpenNewVersion() {

```
    Intent downloadIntent;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/";

        File fileLocation = new File(PATH, "app-release.apk");
        Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,  SHARED_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, fileLocation);
        downloadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        downloadIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        downloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        downloadIntent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(downloadIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            this.grantUriPermission(packageName, apkUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
    }else {
        File fileLocation = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "app-release.apk");
        downloadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        downloadIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        downloadIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileLocation), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    }
    this.startActivity(downloadIntent);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "update Done",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```